# How to get any type of content of specific .ODS cells in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, ods

I am trying to transform an `.ods` file (`content.xml` file from the zip) with XSLT in order to produce a desired `.xml` file.

XSLT uses "fixed" positions of the elements to get the content, but in my `.ods` file I have many blank fields and I don't know how to make them count in XSLT.

Furthermore, I did some experiments with `content.xml` to find out if these blank(empty) cells are saved or not.

In `content.xml` I found something like:

```
<table:table-column table:style-name="co1" table:number-columns-repeated="16384" table:default-cell-style-name="ce1"/>
<table:table-row table:number-rows-repeated="1048576" table:style-name="ro1">
```

Are these values somehow (for example with mathematical calculation) representing the empty cells or actual location of the values in the `.ods` file?

I share my documents here for you to have more clear ideas

The `.ods` example:

[image]

**This is my XSLT file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" 
xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" 
xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" 
xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" 
xmlns:espd="urn:com:grow:espd:02.00.00" xmlns:cac="urn:X-test:UBL:Pre-
award:CommonAggregate" xmlns:cbc="urn:X-test:UBL:Pre-award:CommonBasic" 


<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="office:spreadsheet/table:table">
<xsl:variable name="test" select="table:table-row/table:table-cell"/>
<p><xsl:value-of select="$test/text:p[1]"/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

**And the output is:**

> burak burak5 burak6 burak2 burak3 burak4 burak7 burak9 burak8 burak10

**Question:**

How to get the single values from the cells by applying a transformation on `content.xml`?
(For example: how to reach just cell `D4`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the single values from the cells by applying a transformation on `content.xml`?

The XML data in the `.ods` file's `content.xml` is encoded in this way (always prefixed with the `table:` namespace):

- Each `table-cell` is contained in `table-row`s
- Empty `table-cell`s are encoded empty with [RLE (Run-Length-Encoding)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) indicated by `number-columns-repeated="..."` attributes and must be skipped but counted
- Empty `table-row`s are encoded with RLE, too, indicated by the `number-rows-repeated="..."` attribute
- `table-columns` seem to be used only at the beginning

So, to get a specific cell, e.g. `D4`=`4:4`, the `table-row`s including the skipped ones have to be counted:

```
D4 = 4:4 = Get the fourth `table-row`, add one cell D1, then add number-columns-repeated="2"
```

**This is some XSLT-1.0 code** (also usable with 2.0 and 3.0) with `GetCellValue` examples:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" 
xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" 
xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" 
xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" 
xmlns:espd="urn:com:grow:espd:02.00.00" 
xmlns:cac="urn:X-test:UBL:Pre-award:CommonAggregate" 
xmlns:cbc="urn:X-test:UBL:Pre-award:CommonBasic" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn office style table text espd cac cbc"> 

<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="str" select="'x:1 y:4'" />             <!-- define some coord system -->


  <xsl:template match="/office:document-content/office:body/office:spreadsheet/table:table">
    Table dimensions: <xsl:call-template name="GetDimensions" />
    Value at 5x8: <xsl:call-template name="GetCellValue">
      <xsl:with-param name="x" select="5" />
      <xsl:with-param name="y" select="8" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    Value at 1x4: <xsl:call-template name="GetCellValue">  <!-- use string defined above -->
      <xsl:with-param name="x" select="substring-after(substring-before($str,' '),'x:')" />
      <xsl:with-param name="y" select="substring-after($str,'y:')" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="GetCellValue">
    <xsl:param name="x" />
    <xsl:param name="y" />
    <xsl:variable name="targetRow" select="table:table-row[sum(preceding-sibling::*/@table:number-rows-repeated) + position() - count(preceding-sibling::*/@table:number-rows-repeated)= $y]" />
    <xsl:variable name="targetCell" select="$targetRow/table:table-cell[sum(preceding-sibling::*/@table:number-columns-repeated) + position() - count(preceding-sibling::*/@table:number-columns-repeated) &lt;= $x]" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="$targetCell[last()]/text:p/text()" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="GetDimensions">
    <xsl:variable name="firstRow" select="table:table-row[1]/table:table-cell" />
    <xsl:variable name="firstColumn" select="table:table-row" />
    <xsl:variable name="width" select="count($firstRow)+ sum($firstRow/@table:number-columns-repeated) - count($firstRow/@table:number-columns-repeated)" />
    <xsl:variable name="height" select="count($firstColumn)+ sum($firstColumn/@table:number-rows-repeated) - count($firstColumn/@table:number-rows-repeated)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($width,'x',$height)" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
Table dimensions: 5x12
Value at 5x8: burak9
Value at 1x4: burak4
```

**EDIT:**
I modified one `xsl:call-template` to be used with a string input of a custom format, e.g. `x:1 y:4`.

**Edit2:**
An XSLT-2.0 version which can retrieve multiple cells at once as XML elements can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600462/1305969).

Comment: Thank you very much ! Few things that confuses me ,Imagine that  you have a big file with a lot of information then is this approach feasible?If i have to select lets say 100 fixed position how to approach to that ? The other thing that i did not mention about i need the transformation in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @Sojimanatsu: Yes. It should work with big files, too. So 100 fixed positions should work as good as two. It will be slower, but probably not too slow. BTW this template also works with XSLT-2.0 and 3.0, just change the number ;-).

Comment: I thank you,one more question.Imagine that i get the value of something from the cell by using these x and y kind of koordinate space.I want to equalize this value to something.Ex(x:4 y:5 should represent the value of <example> how can i define this?

Comment: @Sojimanatsu: You can use substring acrobatic and pass that to `call-template`. For example, for the string `$str="x:4 y:5"` use `substring-after(substring-before($str,' '),':')` to get the `4` from the string. Then the complete line would be `xsl:with-param name="x" select="substring-after(substring-before($str,' '),':')`" />`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry not really understand what you mean by that can you implement it in your code as an example please ? so i can review it better thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you very much i have just one question how can we call a template that gets all of the values in .ods file without defining them 1 by 1 (or x and y all the time ) I mean this process somehow should be automatic or recursive lets say gets the only values in the cells and skip the empty lines.I hope i could explain myself